# Could "Wreck-It Ralph" exist as a movie within the canon of Ralph Breaks the Internet?

Tags: wreck-it-ralph, ralph-breaks-the-internet

*Ralph Breaks the Internet* gets very meta.  Within the movie's own lore, Disney exists, as do the characters from Disney movies and Pixar movies.  Moana is featured and recognized as a Disney character, which means *Ralph Breaks the Internet* takes place sometime after 2016.

Could that mean *Wreck-It Ralph*, the 2012 film, also exists in the universe of its own sequel?  Could Ralph go onto the internet and find references to his previous movie?

Comment: Just an idea, if Ralph can do that, then he'll see another Ralph and Penelope from the previous movie. big time speaulation anyways. but if he do that, Wreck it Ralph movies would be more complicated and lose it's elemental value as what it is now. *PS*: If it's references, ratings and reviews, it's a probability. What if he found the 2012 movie and he'll meet Ralph from that one? I dun think it'll go for that beause it'll make a huge mess. I think Ralph already broke 4th wall (maybe not 100%)

Comment: Obligatory Darths&Droids reference: http://darthsanddroids.wikia.com/wiki/Alternate_Universe_strips

Comment: I don't think I can work it into an answer but I really like the idea that the film does exist in Ralph's universe as a 'based on real life events' type film, except Ralph doesn't play himself in the film, Zangief does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, it is entirely possible that the 2012 Wreck-It Ralph film exists in the Wreck-It Ralph universe, although admittedly it is never explicitly mentioned.**

Unfortunately I don't think there is any single piece of hard evidence that proves it. However, I offer this conclusion based on solid reasoning that considers several well established in-universe ideas. I also considered the points you have made in [your answer **against** the film existing in universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/94542/64996) and I offer explanation of them as well, not as a slight against yourself, but simply to try and strengthen your belief in the possibility of the film existing.

Here is my reasoning:

1. **We know that Ralph et al already know of a world outside 
   of their own;** they are aware of the arcade, they know of the
   players,    and they know that these people are able to do things
   that they    themselves cannot (for example, unplug games). So the
   idea of an    unknown 3rd party making a film all about the life and
   times of    Wreck-It Ralph wouldn't be a completely alien concept to
   them. They    may still be surprised to find 'the players' are
   interested enough in    their lives to go to such lengths but it
   still wouldn't be a huge revelation ala [The Truman Show](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120382/).
2. **They have Wikipedia, Facebook and YouTube.** Since Ralph et
   al are new to the internet they probably aren't aware of this for
   the duration of the film, but after just a little time exploring
   on-line **the concept of User Generated Content would be known to
   them.** It isn't clear from either film exactly how much 'the video
   game characters' know about how much influence 'the players' have
   over their world. They know it is based on 'the code' but do they
   know that people outside of their world wrote the code? I'm not
   sure. Opening their mind to User Generated Content gives them the
   concept that 'the players' can generate stuff of their own. Knowing
   this, I believe Ralph could then accept that a film of his
   adventures could exist in universe.
3. Presuming the film universe is very much a mirror of our
   own with a couple of fictional elements, **it is probably safe to
   assume they have [Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/).** (For those that don't know Twitch is an
   online streaming service geared towards sharing videos of people
   playing video games (although it has started branching out into
   other areas)). This would further back the idea of a film of Ralph's
   adventures being possible, the idea that players have a way to
   capture moments from their games to playback and view again later as
   videos. *Ok, this argument would need further 'finessing' to explain
   how a game streaming service would capture out-of-game events, but a
   simple explanation would be that those moments are in-universe CGI.*
4. **We have precedent from another Disney film! [Toy Story](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114709/)!** In
   Toy Story the main character, Woody, is featured as the main
   character in the in-universe TV show Woody's Roundup, yet he knows
   nothing about it until told by another toy in the second film. Given
   that Ralph et al live in a rather closed society (until the
   introduction of the internet) it is perfectly reasonable to assume
   no-one in their circle is aware of the film and hence it goes
   unmentioned to him so he never knows about it.

[image: Woody's RoundUp merch from Toy Story 2]

5. Continuing to use Toy Story for my next thought (which addresses
   [your thoughts](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/94542/64996)), **in Toy Story no-one refers to Woody as the character
   from the hit TV series**, we (the viewer) don't even know he was in a
   TV series until the sequel, and this is an in film,
   definitely-exists-and-is-known-of-by-some-of-the-characters TV
   series. You could argue that in the first film this in-universe show
   hadn't been established so couldn't have been mentioned, but come the
   third film it has been and yet still no-one mentions it. It is only
   mentioned when they are actually talking about the show. So to me
   the argument that no-one refers to him as the character from the
   film doesn't really support the view that it doesn't exist, given
   that the same thing happens here.
6. Even without the Toy Story precedent, **if I was to mention to
   you Ken and Ryu where are you more likely to know them from?** The
   1999 animated movie Street Fighter Alpha or the 1991 video game
   Street Fighter 2? What about Mario and Luigi? The 1985 video game
   Super Mario Bros or the 1993 adventure film Super Mario Bros? It's
   not huge leap to assume 'the players' know and refer to Ralph as the
   guy from the video game even when the film exists because that is
   what he is best known for! Even further, perhaps in-universe the film tanked
   and no-one knows about it other than the gamer geeks and nerds! I could
   imagine why, consider how different the film is compared to the game
   it is based on!

**So in conclusion, yes, a film of Ralph's adventure could exist in universe. There is no strong evidence to suggest it cannot but plenty of circumstantial evidence to suggest it could.**

Answer (score 11):

#### Characters didn't recognize him as a movie character, so *Wreck-It Ralph* (2012) may not have existed in the *Wreck-It Ralph* universe.

The "Wreck-It Ralph" arcade game is fictional, but in the *Wreck-It Ralph* movie's canon, it is a well-known game. There are also fictional websites e.g. [BuzzzTube](https://disney.wikia.com/wiki/BuzzzTube). So this universe already has some fictional canon, even though much of it is based on our own.

In *Ralph Breaks the Internet*, when

> internet users react to Ralph becoming a viral meme

they refer to him as a character from an old arcade game. They don't refer to him as the character from a 2012 Disney movie. So it's possible that in the movie's universe, the 2012 *Wreck-It Ralph* film didn't happen.

Comment: So you knew the answer before. Then why did you ask it?

Comment: @VerNick I don't know the answer. I'm including a self-answer based on what I know. But I'm not accepting it yet. There may be a better answer backed up by evidence from the script, or writer interviews, etc.

Comment: Nobody knows because nobody asked that before.

Comment: @VerNick Answering your own question is an [intended feature](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). There's absolutely nothing wrong with it. It's just someone taking time to share information while sticking to the Stack Exchange format.